# Angular textarea matInput: how can set max length/line + max number of lines

Tags: angular, angular-material, two-way-binding

The following html snippet of code:

```
<mat-form-field class='textarea'>
    <textarea #txtarea matInput (change)='txtAreaChange()' [placeholder]="label" [(ngModel)]='text'></textarea>
    <mat-hint [class.red]="txtarea.value.split('\n').length > textAreaLimit[1]" align="start"> {{txtarea.value ? txtarea.value.split('\n').length : 0}}/{{textAreaLimit[1]}} lines</mat-hint>
    <mat-hint [class.red]="txtarea.value && txtarea.value.split('\n').map( len).max() > textAreaLimit[0]" align="end">Longest line: {{txtarea.value ? txtarea.value.split('\n').map( len).max() : 0}}/{{textAreaLimit[0]}}</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

Defines a textarea input with two-way binding. It does check for size: total number of lines and max length of a line. If these are greater that some constraints given in `textAreaLimit` then the hints become red.

I would like to change it so that the user cannot break this constraints, such as if the max number of line is 3 and there a 3 lines the user cannot add a new line. How can this be done without breaking the two-way binding?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Depending on the size of your screen, a text could `appear` on a single line on desktop, and on 4 lines of a mobile device.. So I don't understand what you want to achieve here .. Define clearly what you call a `line`

Comment: A line here is defined a substring until hitting the next `\n` character, so as to precisely being independent of resizing the textarea box. In other words, after you collect the input value of this textarea, the number of lines is the number of `\n` + 1.

Comment: *rows* and *column*

Comment: so ? is my answer helping you ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this specific need/behavior, you need to create a simple custom validator

```
maxLinesValidator(limit: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
        const exceeded = control.value.length && control.value.split('\n').length > limit;
        return exceeded ? {'maxLines': {value: true}} : null;
    };
}
```

That you'll bind to your FormControl. You can take a look at this working [fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rtf1l) (`src/app/reactive` .ts + html) where the `text` field is validated in real time and displays an error if user exceed the maximum lines limit

Comment: helpful answer :) however you need to change `4` to `limit`

Comment: Hi you could use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/numeric-formatter

Answer (score 6):

use `[maxLength]` property

```
<textarea #txtarea matInput  [maxLength]="maxNo" (change)='txtAreaChange()' [placeholder]="label" [(ngModel)]='text'></textarea>
```

Comment: Isn't it just to constraint the total length after concatenating all the lines? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

Comment: I need a constraint on each length + the total number of lines

Comment: Then set `[rows]="noOfRows"`

Comment: `rows number Specifies the visible number of lines in a text area` this only changes the display, does not restrict the number of lines

Comment: Works well to restrict the number of characters, but does not show a message like "max number of character reached.." . For that , you need to create a custom validator.

Comment: Is there a reason why that's `[maxLength]` and not just `maxLength`, if it doesn't refer to a variable anyway?